# Probability that a 2d SRW starting from $x$ hits $\partial B_n$ before hitting $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

Consider $(S_n)_n$ the simple random walk in two dimensions starting from $x \in B_n:=\{y: ||y||_2 \le n\}$ for a given $n \ge 1$. Denote its law by $\mathbb P_x$.

Let $\tau_{n}:= \inf\{n \ge 1: S_n \in \{0\}\cup \partial B_n\}$ where $\partial B_n$ denotes the exterior border of $B_n$ in the sense of graphs.

My main question is: **What is $\mathbb P_x(S_{\tau_n}=0)$**?

Is it possible to get a closed expression for this? If not, choosing another norm (instead of $||\cdot||_2$) help? If the answer is still negative, could we get an asymptotic expression ($||x||_2$ and $n$)?

This is an analogous to the well-known Gambler's ruin problem. However, here it is not clear how to choose the right martingale to be able to derive the quantities we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic result is presented in [this paper](https://www.groups.ma.tum.de/fileadmin/w00ccg/probability/pdf/Preprints_Publikationen/hatS_subm.pdf). (See Section 2 on page 7). Specifically, if $\tau_R:=\inf\{n\ge 1: S_n\in\partial B(0,R)\}$ and $\tau_0:=\inf\{n\ge 1: S_n=0\}$, for $x\in B(0,R)\setminus \{0\}$ and $R\ge 1$, the probability that $S_n$ started at $x$ hits $\partial B(0,R)$ before the origin is given by
$$
\mathsf{P}(\tau_R<\tau_0)=\frac{a(x)}{a(R)+O(R^{-1})},
$$
as $R\to\infty$, where
$$
a(r)=\frac{2}{\pi}\ln r+\frac{2\gamma+3\ln 2}{\pi}.
$$